# Issue Making Two Colums Equal Height

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

Trying to embed video + chatroom.  If I use 100% width, the chatroom displays at only ~1/4 size. I want chatroom to match exact height of the 16x9 player.

I tried to use matchHeight js but was unable to get that to work, even with no errors in console.

Thank you for looking.

```
<body>
    <?php include_once("../../files/bootstrap-header.php"); ?>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 text-center"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
                <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                    <iframe allowfullscreen class="embed-responsive-item" frameborder="0" height="100%" scrolling="no" src="http://player.twitch.tv/?channel=agentcodydanks69" width="100%"></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                <div class="hidden-md">
                    <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.twitch.tv/embed/runitup/chat" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using Bootstrap 4? There is no longer `-xs` and it uses flebox so that columns would be the same height?

Answer (score 1):

Have you inspected each element to see if there's padding around one of them? May have to set the height for the row to be the height of the smaller element.

Comment: Not sure if I understand that.  There is padding on the document itself (between the two colums and on the sides and bottom of the page).  If I use any pixel amount for heigh instead of 100%, it stretchs as far as I want.  But not to match the player.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use [css flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

```css
.equal--height {
  display: flex;
}

.iframe {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="equal--height">
  <div class="iframe">
    <p>We've the same height</p>
  </div>
  <div class="iframe">
    <p>We've the same height</p>
    <p>Even if i have more text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bootstrap 4 row>col already use flexbox. There's no reason to add it.